# MySQL records being deleted, and I don't know why

Tags: php, mysql, records

I have a serious problem of records being deleted automatically from a specific table in my MySQL database.

After I figured that, I started to check the MySQL binary log to discover what was happening.

Seems that without standard appears DELETE commands, an example of the LOG transcribed below:

```
# at 454
#120605 15:37:48 server id 1 end_log_pos 570 Query thread_id=59 exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1338921468/*!*/;
DELETE FROM intranet_cadeira2 WHERE idCadeira='59'
/*!*/;
# at 570
#120605 15:40:15 server id 1 end_log_pos 686 Query thread_id=66 exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1338921615/*!*/;
DELETE FROM intranet_cadeira2 WHERE idCadeira='29'
/*!*/;
```

The data is inserted correctly, the procedure that inserts data in the tables is the following:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO intranet_cadeira2 (idIntranet,titulo)
VALUES (pidIntranet,ptitulo);
COMMIT;
END
```

But after a while the records are deleted one by one.
I'm racking my brain for it, I appreciate if anyone can help!
I'm pretty sure that it's not a security problem.

Comment: If possible, activate the General Query Log (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html) and see where the query comes from (user, host). It looks like something is actually issuing `DELETE` queries, otherwise I doubt they would otherwise appear in your binary log. I don't remember precisely now, but I believe rolled back transactions would not appear in the binary log (as suggested earlier).

Comment: Look for stored procedures that you or someone else might have written.

Comment: If you have synced servers or replica set, make sure to write to the correct master server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to see the cause from your codes. However, I believe there is a timeout and delete. And maybe once the files get expired, they get deleted from the records.

Also, is it in local server or not?

Comment: But you know if is there any kind of timeout in MySQL?

Comment: Slow malicious sql injection from a script?

Comment: server side issue? can you contact to your hosting server? either its server side issue, or sql injection or there is something wrong in the code that keeps deleting records if not in query.

Comment: I'll try to contact the hosting server, but I'm pretty sure they will not have an answer :P

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where MySQL automatically deleted my entire database. I had a user without a password with permissions specifically assigned to that database. I resolved the issue by simply adding a password to this user, and it worked for me.